# Java is not storing accurate date to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was writing a program to convert string to java.util.Date object and then store the same in the database, the program is running correctly with no errors. But in the MySql the date is not stored correctly, java is storing date which is a yesterday date with respect to date written in the string.
Example- If I write "2018-11-10", it stores "2018-11-09".
My code-

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection con;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Date date = Date.valueOf("2018-11-20"); 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:9090/ProjectScheduler", "root", "tiger");
        PreparedStatement prepare = con.prepareStatement("insert into SchedulerDB(Date) values(?)");
        prepare.setDate(1, date);
        prepare.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

In MySql workbench, I created table as

```
create table SchedulerDB(Date date)
```

when I run select query to see data in table using

```
select * from SchedulerDB
```

Then under the column "Date" in the table- "SchedulerDB", I got 2018-11-19. But I want 2018-11-20 as this is what I wrote in java code. Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: your code work fine

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(
    … ,
    LocalDate.parse( "2018-11-20")
) ;
```

## Details

You are using the terribly designed `java.sql.Date` class. This class unfortunately is a subclass of `java.util.Date` though the documentation strangely tells us to ignore that fact of inheritance. So while `java.sql.Date` *pretends* to represent a date only, it is in fact a moment, a date with a time-of-day set to midnight in some zone and then adjusted to UTC. This is a wretched design, and is one of *many* reasons to *never* use the legacy date-time classes.

For a `DATE` column in SQL, use the modern `LocalDate` class instead.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class truly represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

For database column of a type akin to the SQL-standard `DATE` type, use the  `LocalDate` class in Java.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2018-11-20" );
```

### JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

With no time zone involved, your retrieved value will be the same `2018-11-20` that you stored.

## Example app

Here is a complete example app using the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). As a demo, I have it set to write to an in-memory database rather than persisting to actual storage.

We create a database with a single table, with two columns:

- a sequential number primary key named `pkey_`
- a `DATE` column named `when_`

We insert a couple `LocalDate` objects, and then retrieve the rows to dump to console.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

public class EventDate {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        EventDate app = new EventDate();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        final String driverName = "org.h2.Driver";
        final String catalogName = "event_demo_db";
        final String jdbcPath = "jdbc:h2:mem:" + catalogName + ";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";  // Set delay to keep in-memory database even after last connection closed.

        // Verify JDBC driver.
        try {
            Class.forName( driverName );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Connect, and create database.
        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( jdbcPath ) ;
        ) {
            String sql = null;

            // Create table.
            try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ; ) {
                sql = "CREATE TABLE " + "event_" + " ( \n" +
                        " pkey_ IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY , \n" +
                        " when_ DATE NOT NULL \n" +
                        ") ; \n";
                System.out.println( "TRACE - SQL:\n" + sql );
                stmt.execute( sql );
            }
            System.out.println( "TRACE - Created table `event_`." );

            // Add rows
            sql = "INSERT INTO event_ ( when_ ) \n" +
                    "VALUES ( ? ) " +
                    "; ";

            List < LocalDate > dates = List.of( LocalDate.parse( "2018-11-10" ) , LocalDate.parse( "2018-12-31" ) );
            System.out.println( "Inserting list of LocalDate objects: " + dates );
            try (
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
            ) {
                for ( LocalDate localDate : dates ) {
                    ps.setObject( 1 , localDate );
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            }

            // Retrieve rows
             sql = "SELECT * FROM " + "event_" + " ;";
            try (
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
            ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    int pkey = rs.getInt( "pkey_" );
                    LocalDate when = rs.getObject( "when_" , LocalDate.class );
                    System.out.println( "Row pkey_: " + pkey + " when_: " + when );
                }
            }


        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When run.

> Inserting list of LocalDate objects: [2018-11-10, 2018-12-31]
>
> Row pkey_: 1 when_: 2018-11-10
>
> Row pkey_: 2 when_: 2018-12-31

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: thankyou for your kind-hearted answer, I use LocalDate instead of java.sql.Date but I got the same error i.e. yesterday's date is stored in the database. I am wondering what is the problem now.

Comment: Finally, I got my answer. There is no problem in java code, actually this is a bug of MySql [https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71084]

Comment: @Satnam123 I skimmed that bug report. It seems related to time zone issues. You should know that `java.sql.Date` mentioned at bottom is unfortunately a subclass of `java.util.Date`. So while it *pretends* to represent a date-only value, **`java.sql.Date` actually is a moment**, a date with time-of-day and a time zone adjusted into UTC. So, I'll repeat my advice: Avoid these *terrible awful* old date-time classes! Try the modern  approach with *java.time* classes and the latest JDBC driver and see what happens accessing a SQL `DATE` column with Java `LocalDate` class.